# Is it possible to pass a parameter from a form web part to a data view web part?

Tags: 2007, list-form, data-view-web-part

Is it possible to pass a value from a Form Web Part to a Data View Web Part?
The value from the Form Web Part needs to be passed to a column field in the Data View Web Part for a calculation.

The passed value is not doing any filtering or sorting. I'm trying to do this via SharePoint Designer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is forego the Form Web Part altogether and collect the value in a Data View Web Part (DVWP) as well. Then I pass the value on the Query String in a postback to the same page. The initial DVWP can then grab that value from the query String and do its thing.

Comment: Marc what i actually did was insert normal input type=text and then used a js to post it to the url via QueryString and now collect the data in DATA view web part.But i wanted to use onkeyup with the textbox to redirect to a different URL but its not working.Any ideas

Comment: Forgot to paste my code below:-

<input type="text" class="foobar" value="click a button"/>

<p></p>

<script>
     $("input").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
      }).change();
window.location = "http://localhost:8080/jquery/jq.aspx?c" + $(this).val();
   
</script>